# iPhone Invalid Binary in iTunes Connect

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I uploaded an app as version 1.4 on iTunes Connect but on iTunes it is displaying "Invalid Binary". I tried more times but it is not fixed. I checked icons, appid, build settings etc. I revoked the certificate and generate again and provisioning profile also, i am using same app id which previous version have. Any guess what may be wrong here?
My app in an universal application.

This is the message from apple

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent binary submission for "MyApp". Before your app can be reviewed, the following issues must be corrected:

Corrupt PNG File - The PNG icon file icon-72.png appears to be corrupt.

Once these issues have been corrected , go to the Version Details page and click Ready to Upload Binary. Continue through the submission process until the app status is Waiting for Upload and then use Application Loader to upload the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team'

Comment: then you have to change the corrupt `.png` file before you upload the binary again, it is easy as 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer,
    Project > target > Build Settings > Show All > first item under the Packaging header
        I searched for "pack"
    Toggle Compress PNG Files to NO
And everything is ok

Comment: Hi, sorry to say but i have tried this but it could not solve my problem.